# Installer in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I already have the basic idea of creating an .msi package, but I still can't figure out how to a) put a shortcut to the program on their desktop b) Put the program in the "all apps" section of the start menu and c) edit the dialogs. It is a simple c# app with only one form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following page from [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/) has helped me in the past.  It gives you the details from beginning to end for creating an MSI package.

I don't think they are using VS2015, but it does work with VS2015.

**Creating Shortcuts**

1) Right-click your setup project in *Solution Explorer*, select `View->File System`

2) Select `User's Desktop`, right-click in the right pane and select `Create New Shortcut`

3) In the *Select Item in Project* dialog select `Application Folder` then select the `Primary output...` for your program

This will create a shortcut in the right pane named something along the lines of *Shortcut to Primary output...*.

4) Rename this however you see fit.

5) Right-click `User's Programs Menu` select `Add->Folder`

I like to add a *Company Name* folder here.  All programs I create go into this folder.  This folder is not necessary, but keeps all your programs organized.

6) Right-click `Company Name` select `Add->Folder`

This is a folder for the program itself, rename it whatever the program name is.

7) With the `Program Name` folder selected, right-click in the empty right pane, select `Create New Shortcut`

8) Repeat steps 3 and 4

9) Right-click `File System on Target Machine` select `Add Special Folder->User's Start Menu`

10) With `User's Start Menu` selected, right-click in the empty right pane, select `Create New Shortcut`

11) Repeat steps 3 and 4

All shortcuts are now created.

**Editing Dialogs**

Right-click your setup project in *Solution Explorer*, select `View->User Interface`

From there you will be able to change the Banner Bitmap and some of the wording on the *Welcome* screen.

You will not be able to change the banner text.

Comment: This should be comment OR you should include summary in the post.